# Jquery var confusion -- to $(var) or not to var

Tags: jquery

I can't get my head around when to wrap jQuery objects in $(), e.g.:

`var myButton = $('button.submit');`

Must I then wrap `myButton` in `$()` in order to use it? e.g.:

`$(myButton).click(function(){ //do something});`

or is it...

`myButton.click(function(){ //do something});`

Comment: You only have to wrap it ONCE. The second option is the way to go.

Comment: `$()` returns a jQuery object, so `myButton` does not need to be re-wrapped. It's the cached storage of `$('button.submit');`

Comment: Seems something you could have easily verified yourself, no?

Comment: Thank you. It's complicated. I'm debugging a dynamic form on a production server with no access to the source and it's quicker to ask than to set up a fiddle and futz.

Comment: can't you just press F12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the difference between a JQuery object and a normal vanilla JS DOM Object.

If you have a normal DOM object and need to call a JQuery method, then you have to wrap it.

eg.

```
var thing = document.getElementById('thing');
$(thing).click(//...must wrap to make a JQuery object in order to use the JQuery click() method
```

vs

```
var thing2 = $('#thing2');
thing2.click(//...no need to wrap our object because it's already a JQuery object
```

Comment: Thank you. Does the same go for $(this) and this?

Comment: @KirkRoss yes exactly.  Not sure why but I've been downvoted for something.  Please mark as answer if I've helped.